# How to include a SID-File into a cc65 program on a C64?

Tags: c, audio, c64

I want to include and play .sid files (music for C64 chiptunes) in a cc65 program. Usually sid-files contain a play routine that starts at $1000, how do I link this to my cc65-program?
At the moment I compile my code with cc65 using this command:

```
cl65 -O -o C64test.prg -t c64 C64test.c
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution:

1. Create an .asm file which generates the following code:

   ```
   .export _setupAndStartPlayer

   sid_init = $2000
   sid_play = $2003
   siddata = $2000

   .segment "CODE"

   .proc _setupAndStartPlayer: near
           lda #$00     ; select first tune
           jsr sid_init ; init music
           ; now set the new interrupt pointer
           sei
           lda #<_interrupt ; point IRQ Vector to our custom irq routine
           ldx #>_interrupt
           sta $314 ; store in $314/$315
           stx $315

           cli ; clear interrupt disable flag
           rts     
   .endproc        

   .proc _interrupt
           jsr sid_play
           ;dec 53280 ; flash border to see we are live
           jmp $EA31 ; do the normal interrupt service routine
   .endproc
   ```
2. Call the asm function from C:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <conio.h>
   #include <c64.h>

   extern int setupAndStartPlayer();

   int main(void) {
           printf("Setting up player\n");
           setupAndStartPlayer();
           return 0;
   }
   ```
3. Compile both files using the standard `cc65` `Makefile`, this gives you a `.c64` file with your code, but without the SID data
4. Relocate the SID file using `sidreloc` (the option `-p` defines the new start page, in this case `20` means $2000)

   ```
   ./sidreloc -r 10-1f -p 20 sidfile.sid sidfile2000.sid
   ```
5. Convert the SID file to C64 `.prg` using `psid64`:

   ```
   psid –n sidfile2000.sid
   ```
6. Link the file `sidfile2000.prg` together with the compiled C program using `exomizer` (the number `2061` is the start address of the program, 2061 is the default for `cc65`):

   ```
   exomizer sfx 2061 music.c64 sidfile2000.prg -o final.prg
   ```